# Cefsharp Winform shows images blurred

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

Tools used : .net framework 4.7.2, Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2019

I'm creating a Cefsharp Winform browser.

It works as an simple GUI for my asp.net core app.

**The problem stands on the fact that the pictures are very blurred.**

[image]

If i use firefox/chrome the pictures are high quality and clean.

My Form1.cs :

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
   

    public void InitBrowser()
    {

        CefSharpSettings.WcfEnabled = true;

        var settings = new CefSettings();
        //Absolute path to your applications executable
        settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;

        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
        Cef.RefreshWebPlugins();

        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://localhost:5001")
        {
            MenuHandler = new CustomMenuHandler()
        };
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitBrowser();
    }
```

**the debug_.log :**

[0529/224714.592:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(426)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
[0529/225010.059:WARNING:dns_config_service_win.cc(712)] Failed to read DnsConfig.

**What's wrong with this code?**

Comment: Does the problem reproduce with the example provided at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample your Cef.EnableHighDPISupport call is way too late to be actually enable DPI support,  needs to be called first thing, before your form is created.

Comment: Yes it does give the same problem. How can i enable Cef.EnableHighDPISupport? What should i do?

Comment: Can you test on a different machine? Problem might be related to the GPU error in your log. The minimal example already has DPI awareness set, so that's unlikely related.

Comment: It's just the same even on 2nd pc. When i use firefox, on both pc's, the images are very clear. This seems to be a cefsharp problem.

Comment: How does Chrome behave? Is the second computer using different hardware and windows version? You are the only person reporting this problem I'm aware of so it's likely a hardware/software combination. It's important to remember that CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/README.md

Comment: If Chrome works then try loading chrome://gpu in Chrome to see what it says about your graphics card

Comment: On chrome the images are blurred, on firefox they are not (picture attached). I've included the chrome Gpu log  ->  https://mega.nz/folder/9YkCWLLY#qqa9Ujp3_-Q_ObXExtMKJw

Comment: As Chrome is blurred it's pretty much expected that any Chrome based browser will behave the same. Try using the --disable-gpu command line when you start chrome. If that doesn't work you'll need to search the chromium issue tracker at crbug.com see if there is an open issue that matches yours, create one if you cannot find one.

Comment: Event with "chrome.exe --disable-gpu" its the same result. I'll look at crbug.com